# Access licence number for UPS

Tags: php, ups

I am using [Mark Sanborn UPS Function](http://www.marksanborn.net/php/calculating-ups-shipping-rate-with-php/) to calculate UPS shipping rates with php

In this function you have to change some values of variables already defined

```
 // ========== CHANGE THESE VALUES TO MATCH YOUR OWN ===========  

 $AccessLicenseNumber = '12345678910'; // Your license number  
 $UserId = 'username'; // Username  
 $Password = 'password'; // Password  
 $PostalCode = '12345'; // Zipcode you are shipping FROM  
 $ShipperNumber = '98765'; // Your UPS shipper number
```

but I could not figure out my **$AccessLicenseNumber** for UPS account also my **$ShipperNumber**.

Please any one used this API give me a start.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both of those values are issued by UPS when you request API credentials.

UPS credentials are made up of 4 distinct values- user id, password, access key (license number) and shipper number. Shipper number is optional, but including can affect which rates are returned.

UPS API credentials can be requested here: https://www.ups.com/upsdeveloperkit?loc=en_US

Comment: So the solution is to call UPS customer care isnt it.

Comment: According to you is this th Shipper number or you are talking about something else * 01 – UPS Next Day Air
    * 02 – UPS Second Day Air
    * 03 – UPS Ground
    * 07 – UPS Worldwide Express
    * 08 – UPS Worldwide Expedited
    * 11 – UPS Standard
    * 12 – UPS Three-Day Select
    * 13 Next Day Air Saver
    * 14 – UPS Next Day Air Early AM
    * 54 – UPS Worldwide Express Plus
    * 59 – UPS Second Day Air AM
    * 65 – UPS Saver

Comment: @Wazzy You can obtain the credentials online via their website. See my updated answer. The above numbers are service codes, not shipper numbers. The shipper number is unique value assigned to your account which you can use for API transactions and also for identifying packages sent via the UPS Store. It is around 11 digits, if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 5):

**My UPS ID & Password**

You can easily create in 1 min at UPS website, as long as you have an email.

**UPS account number**

First you need to open a UPS account to get the UPS account number. Each country has a different process to open an account, e.g. In USA, you can simply submit a form to open account at UPS website.

**Access Key**

You have to login to My UPS account to connect your UPS account, and then request Access key to start using UPS shipping and rates API.

1. Create a My UPS account and open a UPS shipper account
2. Login to My UPS account > click Account Summery > Connect your existing shipper account
3. Click "Request an access key" at  [UPS Developer Kit site](https://www.ups.com/upsdeveloperkit)
4. Then you should be able to get the access key.

You can refer to this [detailed guide to get UPS credentials](http://support.postmen.com/article/12-ups-developer-guide-api-credentials).

Answer (score 2):

UserID and Password are the credentials you use for UPS.com and the shipper number is your UPS account number. The access license number is provided by UPS when you signup for the OnLine tools.