# UPS "AccessLicenseNumber"

Tags: web-services, api, licensing, ups

This question is related to Stackoverflow Question -> [Access licence number for UPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684087/access-licence-number-for-ups)

When I registered for Developer APIs, I was given a 4-part credential: User ID, Password, Access Key, and Shipper Number.  I used this and the CIE URL to get rates, print shipping labels, etc.  So far so good.  Everything works.  I have been able to build and test desktop and web GUIs that use UPS API.

Now I understand that I need to implement UPS Registration API and Licensing API to apply for certification.  I applied with UPS for this and received the API package.  Again, so far so good.  Now, I have two questions:

1- I understand that we can use the Registration API to authenticate existing UPS accounts for end users to access my application.  We can also use it to allow the end user to create one or more new UPS accounts for use with the application.  If Registration API takes care of this, what is the use of the Licensing API?  UPS documentation isn't widely available and the documentation that comes with the API kit is very minimal.

2- My app will use the end users' UPS account numbers for shipping, but which Access Key should it use?  Should it use the Access Key of each end user, or my Access Key for everyone?  If the former, then should this end-user Access Key be obtained using the Licensing API?  Is that the Licensign API's purpose?

In essence, I think both questions are the same but you can see how perplexed I am with respect to this requirement of implementing Registration and Licensing APIs!

Any insight from you experts would be REALLY great!

UPDATE:
Just wanted to add another question:

3- I am using UPS Web Services for all UPS functionality.  The package that contains Licensing API and Registration API has a "Reference.cs" for the Registration API but not for Licensing API (only XSDs in that folder).  Is the Licensing API not available as Web Service?

Comment: Anyone?  Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Questions on the licensing API should be referred to the folks at UPS Ready. This is not the proper forum.

Comment: Yes, that's what I gathered as well.  Until a few days back I wasn't aware of it and was only making preliminary research into the UPS API.  I've now figured that UPS Ready program management is the best (or rather ONLY) source of info for this purpose.  Thanks for confirming that my latest understanding is correct.  I appreciate your advice.